# Find first match in two sorted ranges using STL

Tags: c++, stl, std

I have two sorted ranges. I would like to find the first matching element in the ranges, if any.

The **operations (on sorted ranges)** sections in [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm) do not appear to contain exactly what I want. `std::set_intersection` is close, but it finds *all* the matching elements.

Of course I could write my own template algorithm, but it's a bit of a chore to write algorithms up to the STL quality standard.

Another option is to somehow adapt `std::set_intersection` by using a special output iterator. We could write something like

```
template <typename T>
struct OneElementIter
{
    T &operator*() {
        if (full) return dummy;
        full = true;
        return t;
    }
    void operator++() {}
    bool full = false;
    T t;
    T dummy;
};
```

and use it for the output iterator of `std::set_intersection`. This will waste effort scanning the input ranges past the first match, but it's still O(n) complexity.

However, writing STL-quality iterators is a chore too. I'm not aware of anything in `<iterator>` that can do this without writing a new iterator class.

If the STL container library included a fixed-size FIFO queue whose `push_back` is a no-op when full, then we could use a `std::back_inserter` on a queue of size `1` as the output iterator. But no such container exists.

Is there any elegant way to do this with existing STL tools I'm missing?

Answer (score 2):

This doesn't technically answer the question since you want an STL solution. However, range-v3 has been the basis for a lot of the additions to the STL in C++20, and so I expect this solution to work in a future version, hopefully even in C++23.

```
auto first = *std::begin(rv::set_intersection(vec_1, vec_2) | rv::take(1));
```

where `rv` is just a namespace alias for `ranges::views`.

In this solution `rv::set_intersection` is just the lazy version of `std::set_intersection`. Since only the first element is `rv::take`n, the remaining matching elements are not computed, which satisfies your requirements. In fact, `vec_1` and/or `vec_2` can even be infinite ranges.

The only requirement is that there be at least one matching element, or else it invokes undefined behavior.

Here's a [demo](https://godbolt.org/z/r6vT7a).

Comment: That looks nice. Wouldn't the undefined behavior for no match only be a concern for infinite ranges? [cppreference says](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/ranges/take_view) that the `std::views` version of `take` is a "view of the first N elements from an underlying sequence, or all elements if the underlying sequence contains fewer than N."

Comment: I am excited for the next round of ranges features in the STL, especially `accumulate`-like algorithms will cover a lot of the current gap between iterators and ranges.

Comment: @japreiss The `take` is fine, but the dereference of `begin` on an empty range would invoke UB. You could check for that case of course, but I didn't think it was important to add that code.

Comment: oh yeah, OK. just making sure the `take` itself isn't a problem.

Comment: Why do we even need `| rv::take(1)`? At least theoretically it seems completely redundant.

Comment: @Evg I'm not *entirely* sure about this, but without the `| take(1)`, I think the entire `set_intersection` would need to be computed before `begin` could be called, which defeats the purpose. I suppose a compiler could optimize it out, but I'm not sure that optimization is even possible if the ranges are infinite.